# Capture id between square brackets in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

From using mysql regex I want to check id exits or not in secure brackets

fields value

```
{"id":"66","value":"2480"},{"id":"69","value":["25","27"]}
```

Query:

```
(fields REGEXP '{"id":"69","value":[^{]*("25"|"27")')
```

This is not working

If user check id=66 and value=2480 record will show, same if user check id=69 and value=25 or 27 record will show.

How can I get this?

Comment: Does changing `[^{]` to `[^}]` work for you?

Comment: Note that if you have a recent version of MySQL, the JSON data type is supported since MySQL 5.7.8. So in this case, convert your column to JSON once and for all, then you will no more need to use REGEXP but simple and faster queries. More informations here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: MariaDB also supports JSON, but in a different way.